# How to generate n^r variations of an array (i.e. variations with repetition of nCk)

Tags: algorithm, c#-4.0, permutation

my question is based from topcoder's recent SRM (628 500 point question), i'm trying to solve the string parsing question by brute force since the number of solutions cannot exceed 5^5 and I'm very close. My question is how would I go about generating not only n! permutations but n^r permutations in c#. Using an adaptation of Knuth's lexicographical permutation algorithm my solution works but not for cases when the answer (the winning permutation) has repeated characters.

input example: "X{}]X{X{}]X]"

```
        public string ifPossible(string expression)
    {
        char[] c = new char[6] { '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']' };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(expression);
        int j = 0;
        special(sb);

        while (my_next_permutation(c) && sb.ToString().Contains('X'))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sb.Length;i++)
            {
                if (sb[i] == 'X')
                    sb[i] = c[j++];
            }
            special(sb);
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Clear();
                sb.Append(expression);
                special(sb);
                j = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }


        if (sb.Length > 0)
            return "impossible";
        return "possible";
    }
    void special(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        while (sb.ToString().Contains("()") || sb.ToString().Contains("[]") || sb.ToString().Contains("{}"))
        {
            while (sb.ToString().Contains("()"))
                sb.Replace("()", "");
            while (sb.ToString().Contains("[]"))
                sb.Replace("[]", "");
            while (sb.ToString().Contains("{}"))
                sb.Replace("{}", "");
        }
    }
    public Boolean my_next_permutation(char[] a) 
    {
        int N = a.Length, i = N - 2;
        for (; i >= 0; i--)
            if (a[i] < a[i + 1])
                break;
        if (i < 0) return false;

        for (int j = N - 1; j >= i; j--)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[i])
            {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (N + i + 1) / 2; j++)            
        {
            var temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[N + i - j];
            a[N + i - j] = temp;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I take it `n^r` permutations means for a string `r` characters long you want all possible strings where you have `n` characters to choose from ?  So, we start with an array `aux[r]` all values set to zero, and start counting at one end, modulo `n`, and carrying ?  Or am I missing a vital part of the puzzle ?

Comment: Sounds right to me @gmch.  OP, think of it this way: if you wanted to generate all 5-digit numbers, allowing repetition of digits, how would you do it?  This is much easier than generating permutations IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I could have used the array idea as gmch and jrh suggested but I
ended up using this:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(char[] list, int? resultSize = null, bool withRepetition = false)
    {
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        char[] result = new char[resultSize.HasValue ? resultSize.Value : list.Length];
        var indices = new int[result.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            indices[i] = withRepetition ? -1 : indices.Length - i - 2;

        int curIndex = 0;
        while (curIndex != -1)
        {
            indices[curIndex]++;
            if (indices[curIndex] == list.Length)
            {
                indices[curIndex] = withRepetition ? -1 : curIndex - 1;
                curIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                result[curIndex] = list[indices[curIndex]];
                if (curIndex < indices.Length - 1)
                    curIndex++;
                else
                    yield return new string(result);
            }
        }
   }
```

I got the idea from this page http://noldorin.com/programming/CombinatoricsUtilities.cs.txt
All credit given to Alex Regueiro.